# Why test against null in this example?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I follow this tutorial on commands in MVVM:

https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/22.3.php

Here's an example code of a Command from the tutorial

```
private RelayCommand addCommand;
public RelayCommand AddCommand
{
    get
    {
        return addCommand ??
            (addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
            {
                Phone phone = new Phone();
                Phones.Insert(0, phone);
                SelectedPhone = phone;
            }));
    }
}:
```

As I understand the logic, we have a private backing field `addCommand` and public property `AddCommand` which only has a getter. In said getter the field addCommand is tested against `null`. If `addCommand != null` then its value is returned. Otherwise a new exemplar of `RelayCommand` class is returned. But since  AddCommand doesn't have a setter, including a private one, doesn't it mean `addCommand` field will always return `null`? Why test against `null` a field that will always return `null`? Why keep such a field at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be missing the part in C# where any assignment returns the value that was assigned, as a result

```
x = 1
```

Returns 1

This means you can do

```
y = x = 1
```

And y ends up as 1 too, because the result of `x=1` is 1 and this is assigned to y

As a result the pattern you see offers a one time creation of a value for your `addCommand`; if `addCommand` has a value then the existing value is returned, if it does not (i.e. it is `null`) then the `??` ensures the right hand side is executed which performs an assignment: `addCommand` receives a new value, which is then returned as the "result of the assignment" (and ultimately is returned as the result of the get). This `addCommand` then survives to the next time it's called, meaning that the creation of it is only done once, and upon first demand rather than by default upon creation of the enclosing class (we call it lazy loading/lazy instantiation..)

```
private int x = null;

//if x is not null return x otherwise return: (assign 1 to x and return 1)
get { return x ?? (x = 1); }
```

---

Footnote:

You might consider refactoring your code as:

```
get
{
    if(addCommand == null){
        addCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
        {
            Phone phone = new Phone();
            Phones.Insert(0, phone);
            SelectedPhone = phone;
        }
    }

    return addCommand;
}
```

It's not significantly longer, and it's equivalently performant, so if you'd have understood it better, then the time it saved you in not having to ask on SO about it would forever be profit :) - sometimes C# devs can go too far in the quest for finding some compact, one-line way to express intent and end up with something that is equally "computer readable" but less "human readable", and if you can't understand it at a glance it might well be a needless waste of your time every time you come to look at it

Comment: why not just `get {return new RelayCommand(...)}`?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov that will create a new command every time the property is called. This approach is a lazy load technique. The first time the property is called it will create the command. Subsequent calls will return the value that was created in the first call.

Comment: Indeed; added a footnote about this; consider whether you should let this pattern remain in your code. If it confused you, it might confuse someone else, and taking 20 seconds out to jiggle it round might mean you don't find yourself confused in 6 months when you come across it again (or the next person does etc)